# Can't get Django REST to save POST object request in model

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Trying to allow users to create an object and save it in my model.  My front-end `POST` requests are getting a 201 confirmation response, so no traceback error from the backend. The data seems to be getting serialized but not saved in my model.

Here is my code...

model.py:

```
class Bucket(models.Model):

    category_options = (
        ('personal', 'Personal'),
        ('social', 'Social'),
    )


    class BucketObjects(models.Manager):
        def get_queryset(self):
            return super().get_queryset()

    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='buckets')
    admin_user = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='admin_user')
    guest_user = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='guest_user', blank=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=category_options)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, blank=True)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from = "random_string", blank=True) 
    stock_count = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    stock_list = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=6,null=True),size=30,null=True, blank=True)
    about = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    objects = models.Manager()
    bucketobjects = BucketObjects()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created',)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.stock_list:
            self.stock_count = len(self.stock_list)
            super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

serializer.py:

```
class BucketCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Bucket
        fields = ('owner','category','name','about')
        read_only_fields = ['owner']
    
    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = self.context['request'].user
        bucket = Bucket.objects.create(
         owner=user, 
         **validated_data
        )
        bucket.save()
        return bucket
```

view.py:

```
class CreateBucket(generics.CreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    serializer_class = BucketCreateSerializer
    queryset = Bucket.objects.all()
```

How can I go about solving this?

Comment: It seems `self.stock_list` is always `False` for the newly created object

Comment: Is the dataset that is serialized is `Query Dict` (try  by printing the request.data) if it's type is `Query dict` try converting it into a `dict`

Comment: @Crosby, yes this seemed to be the error. I created a proper loop and added an else statement. Things are now working fine. Thank you!